# Add group rwx permissions to a folder

Tags: linux, unix, permissions

I have a folder named `docs`, how do I add rwx permissions for group `devs` to docs?

I tried:

`chmod -R g+rwx docs`

but I don't know where to specify that it's the devs group I want to grant permissions for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you did is right but first you may have to change the group to "devs" with the [chgrp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chgrp) or [chown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chown) command.
Note that in unixland a file only has one group.

Comment: A file/folder only has one group unless you have ACLs turned on.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for `chown` or `chgrp`

Comment: `chown [user]:[group] [file]` or `chgrp [group] [file]`

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the group of the file using the chgrp command.

Answer (score 1):

First thing to do is:

```
chown -R <user>:devs docs
```

then:

```
chmod -R 070 docs
```

That will give rwx to the group of docs and no permissions to the rest, if you want the owner to have the same permissions then do:

```
chmod -R 770 docs
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably have umask set to 0022. Do:

```
umask 0002
chmod -R g+rwx
umask 0022
```

That should work

Comment: `umask` affects file creation. You don't need to change it in order to be able to `chmod` a file.